# Band theory of solids: Kronig–Penney model parameters question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, solid-state-physics, schroedinger-equation, crystals

In the [Kronig–Penney model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_one-dimensional_lattice#Kronig%E2%80%93Penney_model), we assume that the periodic potential of the crystal is modeled as a square well.

The period of the potential is $d$, where $d=a+b$.

$a$: the width of the zero potential region, and

$b$: is the width of the barrier.

And with the standard assumptions of the Kronig–Penney model, and [Bloch's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch%27s_theorem):
$$\psi(x)=u(x)e^{ikx}$$ where $u(x)$ is the modulation I suppose? (I.e., varying amplitude?).

What does $k$ represent here? I know that it is the wave number. However, isn't $k=\frac{2\pi *p}{h}$ ([de Broglie formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory))? Implying that $$k^2 = \frac{2m(E-U_0)*4*\pi^2}{h^2}$$

Now, in the textbook, when solving the [Schrödinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) in the free region, the author introduces the parameter $\alpha$, where $$\alpha^2 =\frac{2mE*4\pi^2 }{h^2}$$
What I do not get is, isn't $\alpha = k$ in the zero potential region?
Furthermore, in the barrier region, the author again introduces $\beta^2=\frac{2m(U-E)*4\pi^2}{h^2}$
Similarly, isn't $\beta^2 = -k^2$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Now my question is, what does $k$ represent here? I know that it is the wave number. However, isn't $k=\frac{2\pi p}{h}$ (De broglie formula)?

It depends on what you mean by $p$. If you mean the linear momentum - the infinitesimal generator of spatial translations which is conserved in the presence of spatial translation symmetry - then the answer is *no*. Linear momentum is (unsurprisingly) not conserved in this system, because you have a spatially varying potential$^\dagger$ - you can attribute the non-conservation of momentum to scattering off of the crystal lattice. As a result, the (generalized) energy eigenfunctions of this system (i.e. the Bloch waves) are *not* (generalized) eigenfunctions of the linear momentum operator, which you can check straightforwardly (the clue is that $u'(x) \neq 0$).

The correct interpretation for $p$ is a related concept called *crystal momentum* or *pseudomomentum*, which may be understood as momentum modulo $2\pi/d$, where $d=a+b$ as you define in your question. Unlike linear momentum, the pseudomomentum *is* conserved in this system. You might think of this as the statement that while the linear momentum is not conserved, it may only change by integer multiples of $2\pi / d$.

> Implying that $k^2 = \frac{2m(E-U_0)*4*\pi^2}{h^2}$?

An equation of this kind would only hold if $U=U_0$ is a constant, which is of course not true here. It is true in the "free" region where $U = 0$, and separately true in the "barrier" region where $U=U_0$, but $U_0 \neq 0$  so $k^2$ certainly can't satisfy your equation in both regions at the same time. This is why your author introduces one value $\alpha^2$ for the free region, and one value $\beta^2$ for the barrier region.

---

$^\dagger$If we allow the crystal lattice to have its own (rigid) dynamics, then the linear momentum becomes conserved once again - when the momentum of an electron changes, the momentum of the crystal lattice changes in the other direction, with the sum total being constant. However, this introduces significant complexity to our description while adding essentially no useful physical content, so instead we simply dispense with momentum conservation and treat the lattice as fixed. This is similar the approximation we make when treating the Earth as fixed when we study the bouncing of a basketball.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the linear momentum. I got it now, why the need to define alpha and beta, and that k is no longer equal to the equation that I wrote previously. The last paragraph really solved my confusion. Now I get it why, mathematically, we have to introduce alpha and beta. But one last question: What does "k" physically represent now in the model? (Sorry If this is a stupid question).

Comment: @Nero It's not a stupid question. I tried to address this in the 2nd paragraph - $k$ is the *crystal momentum* (or *pseudomomentum*). It is a conserved quantity in this model, in the same way that momentum is a conserved quantity in a model which has translation symmetry.